# UIButton not showing up in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have set up my button as so:

```
CGRect button1Frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
self.button1 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:button1Frame];
[self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goToController1:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
self.button1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.button1.opaque = YES;
self.button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.button1 setTitle:@"B1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:self.button1];
```

with my sender:

```
- (void) goToController1:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
}
```

and my view controller has been initialized properly.
What would cause my button not to show up? I have checked to make sure everything is being called properly.

Comment: Not the cause of your issue, but just a note that you should generally use the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` control event for buttons, rather than touch down. It's a better user experience, as the action only takes place once you release your finger within the button, and gives you the opportunity to cancel.

Comment: Thank you. I will switch that now. Hope someone answers the question though. There are a lot of posts about this but none seemed to solve my problems.

Comment: Is this code within your viewController? Where are you calling it?

Comment: Yes, this is within the view controller.
Sorry for not making that explicit.

Comment: Where in the view controller?

Comment: Where is `self.button1` defined?

Comment: Being called in view did load.

Comment: self.button1 is a property that is part of the view controller which it exists in.

Comment: is your view linked correctly to the outlet in Interface Builder?

Comment: Try putting it in viewWillAppear - self.view may still be nil in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Programmatically done. No interface builder...

Comment: Changing to viewwillappear made no changes.

Comment: Are you sure that `self.view` has appeared or is visible?

Comment: Yes. I am sure because everything else happening in the view is working as normal.

Comment: If i make a uiview container for the button, the container will show up but no button inside of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try this:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

And then set the frame like this:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20);
```

The UIButton buttonWithType: method fixed my problem at one point.  Not sure if it will make a difference in this case though.  Just something to try.

Comment: As of iOS 7, `UIButtonTypeRoundedRect` is deprecated - you should use `UIButtonTypeSystem` instead. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW35)